# Combining capture groups, different match numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get some regex to work, but I cannot get the capture group to share(?) a match. I would like it so if the regex matches "id", it uses the regex to match all numbers (17 long), and if it matches "profile", it matches alphanumeric. Right now when I try the below, it works, but the match for profile is the 3rd and 4th instead of 1st and 2nd. Hopefully this makes sense.

Here is a regex test: https://regex101.com/r/wS2pL0/2

```
http://community.com/id/something123
http://community.com/profile/12345678901234567

(?:https?:\/\/)(?:www\.)?community\.com\/(?:(id)\/(\w{3,32})|(profile)\/(\d{17}))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var regex   = /(?:https?:\/\/)(?:www\.)?community\.com\/(id\/\w{3,32}|profile\/\d{17})/; 
        var string  = document.getElementById('url').value;
        var match   = string.match(regex);

        if (match) {
            var mat = match[1].split('/');
            if (mat[0] == 'profile' && mat[1].length === 17) {
                console.log("true" + mat[1]);
            } else {
                console.log("false");
            }
        } else {
            console.log('nothing');
        }
```